# WHERE clause returning no results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM public."Matches"
WHERE 'Matches.Id' = '24e81894-2f1e-4654-bf50-b75e584ed3eb'
```

I'm certain there is an existing match with this Id (tried it on other Ids as well), but it returns 0 rows. I'm new to querying with PgAdmin so it's probably just a simple error, but I've read the docs up and down and can't seem to find why this is returning nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes are only used for strings in SQL. So `'Matches.Id'` is a string constant and obviously not the same as `'24e81894-2f1e-4654-bf50-b75e584ed3eb'` thus the WHERE condition is always false (it's like writing `where 1 = 0`)

You need to use double quotes for identifiers, the same way you did in the FROM clause.

```
WHERE "Matches"."Id" = ...
```

In general the use of quoted identifiers is strongly discouraged.

Comment: May I ask why it's discouraged? When I run it with Id = 'foo' with no quotes like "Id", it gives an error.

Comment: Because the need for quoted identifiers creates more problems than they are worth it. See e.g. here:  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: I see, thanks for the info! Wish I knew this when creating the db, looks like I'm stuck with the double quotes for now.